# How to use @Autowired correctly in spring boot standalone app

Tags: spring, spring-boot, constructor, null, autowired

I've learned a lot recently about Spring and one thing i think i might be misunderstanding is the @Autowired annotation, especially when using it in constructors.  You see, the app i'm developing is a service so basically EVERYTHING is initialized within a constructor.  The only actual user-driven events that happen are buttons that restart certain modules of the service.  This is my main method :

```
ConfigurableApplicationContext ctx = new SpringApplicationBuilder(MDHIS_Service.class)
        .headless(false).web(false).run(args);
    java.awt.EventQueue.invokeLater(() -> 
    {
        MDHIS_Service frame = ctx.getBean(MDHIS_Service.class);
        frame.setSize(1024, 768);
        frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        frame.setVisible(true);
    });
```

This is the constructor of my main class, where basically everything happens.  I have omitted the calls to the methods initializing each module to shorten it :

```
@Autowired
public MDHIS_Service(GlobalParamService globalParamService, LogEntryService logentryService, InterfaceService interfaceService, 
        ConnectionService connectionService, OutboundMessageService outboundMessageService, OutboundMessageHistoryService outboundMessageHistoryService, 
        InboundMessageService inboundMessageService, FacilityService facilityService, ModuleStatusService moduleStatusService,
        SequenceService sequenceService) 
{
    this.globalParamService = globalParamService;
    this.logEntryService = logentryService;
    this.interfaceService = interfaceService;
    this.connectionService = connectionService;
    this.outboundMessageService = outboundMessageService;
    this.outboundMessageHistoryService = outboundMessageHistoryService;
    this.inboundMessageService = inboundMessageService;
    this.facilityService = facilityService;
    this.moduleStatusService = moduleStatusService;
    this.sequenceService = sequenceService;
}
```

My main class has a private final global variable for each service.  Each module is a separate thread and i'm finding myself having to pass those variables to the constructor of each module which in term stores them into it own private final variables.  The way i'm doing things right now @Autowired is pretty much useless since i'm having to pass the instance around.  Is there a way to better use @Autowired?  This service is used as the backend for a large web app and i find myself making much better use of the annotation in there.  I did a lot of research on this topic and i did try the @PostContruct annotation but all i ever got was null services.

Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks!

Comment: Have you configured component scan properly? https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/using-boot-spring-beans-and-dependency-injection.html

Comment: My main class is annotated with this :
    @SpringBootApplication(scanBasePackages = "com.mdenis.mdhis_service") which is the base package for every other package and classes.  Would this do the same?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out my problem, and it was a pretty dumb one.  First off, i had not annotated my main class with @Component so Spring never bothered to inject the dependencies in it.  Secondly, I did not realize that a method annotated with @PostContruct would run by itself after the constructor runs WITHOUT NEEDING TO EXPLICITELY BE CALLED!

I moved all my initialization code to an init method annotated with @PostConstruct and annotated my main class with @Component, everything is working now!

Answer (score -1):

You typicall don't have to use a constructor + @Autorwired, you can directly use autowired on fields and spring would fill the dependencies for you:

```
@Component
public class MDHIS_Service {

@Autowired
private GlobalParamService globalParamService;

}
```

What is important to understand is that for spring to work, you must let it create the objects for you, and not calling the constructors explicitely. It would then fill the dependencies as needed. This is done by declaring the service as a component (for example with the @Component annotation) and never create the service yourself but getting them from dependency injection.

The first object you start with has to have been created by spring and returned by the application context.

What you gain in exchange is that you don't have to forwared everything explicitely. A sub-sub-sub service quite distant from the root of the application can depend on anything it has visibility without you having to forward the reference all the way.

I would advise to take a look a the spring reference documentation, it quite detailled and complete:

https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/core.html#spring-core

Edit: I'll try to clarify a bit with an example... What do the init code of the various service actually does ?

Maybe it set the dependencies. Then just autowire them:

```
@Component 
MySubService {

@Autowired MySubSubService mySubSubService;

}
```

Maybe it does some more thing than setting fields so you can add on top an init method that do it and this init method can eventually call the other services.

```
@Component 
MySubService {

@Autowired MySubSubService mySubSubService;

@PostConstruct
public void init() {
//Init code that may use mySubSubService.
}
}
```

You don't have to declare a constructor and forward dependencies yourself, sprint does it for you.

The only case where you'd have problem is if finally you need some parameters that are not dependency to the init method. But even in that case you could do it from you main code. That's actually what you did with the main service calling the various setters rather than messing with the constructor to set theses values.

Comment: Since i'm initializing my JFrame via ctx.getBean() i definitely have this part covered.  From testing i have done in the past, the autowired beans are only null when accessed from a constructor which, as i said, is 95% of this app's code.  I did add the @Component annotation to my main class but it seems no matter what i do the services are always null in any code called by the constructor.  It's been a while but i do recall annotating methods called by the constructor with PostConstruct but that didn't work either.

Comment: To clarify why do you need to access the services variable inside the constructor actually ? You may not even need a constructor at all if you use Autowired and PostConstruct would be on a standard method, not a constructor. Also be sure you don't actuall do the constructor call yourself with new) but let spring do it.

Comment: My service is basically a JFrame which initializes 4 modules (connections, messaging, maintenance and web connector).  It is used as a backend for a hospital information system.  Nobody ever gets to interact with this application directly (aside from 4 restart buttons which kill individual modules and restart them).  The initialization code is all in the main class' constructor which is why i need autowired services to be accessible from there.

Comment: From your example there no initialization code in the constructor, only dependency injection of the fields... You should decide if you want to let spring do it for you or handle it manually. (Ah you removed it unfortunately). Anyway you don't need to call inside that constructor and give the dependency explictely as you are basically not using spring. You can just autowired the field of the sub components.

Comment: yep, what i did wrong is exactly what you said, thanks a lot for your help!  I am very familiar with using Spring in a web app but there was a couple of things i was missing to be able to apply dependency injection to a Swing app.